# Data scraping text without css path R

Tags: css, r, web, web-scraping

Hello I am writting to you because I am breaking my head to find a way and scrap data out of a webpage("https://nabtu.org/about-nabtu/official-directory/building-trades-local-councils-overview/").
I am doing this for practice and just to learn how to scrap data.I am trying to scrap out the contact data of the above mentioned webpage(Office,Fax,email) but I am unable to do it since there is no certain css path I can get with  Selectorgadget.I am using R and the scrip I am using is kind of like this.

```
library(rvest)
page_name <-read_html("page html")


page_name %>%
html_node("selector gadget node") %>%
html_text()
```

I scraped all the other data I just cant scrap this contact information.
Any help will be appreciated because my head is gonna blow.Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"You may not … (h) use any automatic or manual process to harvest information from the Site;"_ Part of your self-education should be learning to not violate site terms of use/terms of service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where the problem is. Each contact block has a `.council-list` list class. Using that, you can extract the contact information seperately. Afterwards, use some string/regex operations to extract the exact fields.

```
library(rvest)
page_name <- read_html('https://nabtu.org/about-nabtu/official-directory/building-trades-local-councils-overview/')
contact_strings = page_name %>%
  html_nodes('.council-list') %>%
  html_text()

# Filter out strings that don't contain contact information
contact_strings = grep(x = contact_strings, 'Email|Fax|office', ignore.case = T, value = T)

# Extract infomration 
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
office = str_extract(contact_strings, 'Office:[^[:alpha:]]*')
fax = str_extract(contact_strings, 'Fax:[^[:alpha:]]*')
email = str_extract(contact_strings, 'Email: [^ ]*')
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I am new to the field and trying to get used to it.